# Sending emails with attachment using VBA

Tags: vba, outlook

I want to automatically send emails through Outlook. It gets as far as `myAttachments.Add` and states:

> Object doesn't support this property or method.

I've tried this a few different ways, but errors continue on the attachment section. All other sections work creating the email.

What am I doing wrong?

```vb
Sub Send_Emails()

    Dim OutlookApp As Outlook.Application
    Dim OutlookMail As Outlook.MailItem
    Dim myAttachments As Outlook.Attachments

    Set OutlookApp = New Outlook.Application
    Set OutlookMail = OutlookApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)
    Set myAttachments = OutlookMail.Attachments
    
    myAttachments.Add Source:=ThisWorkbook, Type:=olByValue
  
    With OutlookMail
        .BodyFormat = olFormatHTML
        .HTMLBody = "Attached is the Transaction Report"
        .To = "email@yahoo.com"
        .Subject = "Transaction Report"
        .Send
    End With
    
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

```
With OutlookMail
    
    .To = "email@nowherenoplace.com"
    
    .Attachments.Add ThisWorkbook.fullName
    
    .Display

End With
```